# C palindrome program - undefined reference to main

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I wrote an function, which checks, if string of char is palindrome or not.

```
//pan.c

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "funs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool palindrom(char napis[])
{
    int begin, middle, end, length = 0;

    while(napis[length] != '\0')
      length++;

    end = length - 1;
    middle = length;

    for (begin = 0; begin < middle; begin++)
      {
        if(napis[begin] != napis[end])
        {
          return false;
          break;
        }
        end--;
      }
      if(begin == middle)
        return true;
}
```

I also created funs.h

```
//funs.h
#include <stdbool.h>
bool palindrom();
```

Now, I'm trying to use this function in my main function

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "funs.h"


int main()
{
    char text[100];
    bool result;

    printf("Enter an char: ");
    scanf("%s", text);
    result = palindrom(text);
    if(result)
    {
        printf("Brawo!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Gówno!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also created makefile:

```
# Makefile

all: main

main: main.o pan.o
    clang -o main main.o pan.o

main.o: main.c
    clang -c main.c

pan.o: pan.c
    clang -c pan.c

clean:
rm -f main *.o *~
```

Everything seems fine and works in single file, but when I try to compile them separately they "don't see" each other. Makefile also seems to work badly, but I can't see any mistakes. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: `bool palindrom();` defines a function that can receive any number of parameter, all by default as `int`. So that is wrong...

Comment: You have missed somthing in `bool palindrom();` declaration, should be `bool palindrom(char*);`.

Comment: @MateuszTrzeciak: _but when I try to compile them separately they "dont see" each other_, what is the error you are getting during compilation?

Comment: I changed it, but still there's something wrong :(

Comment: @MateuszTrzeciak I don't see any issues with compilation! I tried on my PC and it compiles fine. What is the compiler error you are getting?

Comment: @Gaurav When I try "make" command it returns "_makefile:15: *** missing separator. Stop._" comment and do nothing.

When I'm compiling pan.c with _"clang pan.c -Wall --pedantic -std=c11 -o pan_" command:
**1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: [Edit] such essential diagnostic info into your post. _"does not work"_ is not a problem description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try "make" command it returns "makefile:15: *** missing separator. Stop." comment and do nothing.

Did you actually look at line 15 of your makefile?  Notice that it's flush against the margin instead of indented by a tab character.

> When I'm compiling pan.c with "clang pan.c -Wall --pedantic -std=c11 -o pan" command: 1 warning generated. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-l‌​inux-gnu/crt1.o: In function _start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to main'

Indeed, your pan.c does not have a main() function.  So don't try to compile it by itself.  How about

`clang main.c pan.c -Wall --pedantic -std=c11 -o pan`